# In C++ can there be a range of values in a switch statement?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, range

I wanted to find out if its possible to have ranges in a switch case statement. 
When i run the below code i get the following error: error: score cannot appear in a constant-expression
     case score < 60:

```
int score;

cout << " enter score";
cin >> score;

switch(score)
{

case score < 60:
    cout << "F";
    break;

case score < 70:
    cout << "D";
    break;

case score < 80:
    cout << "C";
    break;

case score < 90:
    cout << "B";
    break;

default: cout << "A";
}

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, you can't do that. Just use `if(score < 60) { } else if (score < 70) { }` etc. It's probably less typing too.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

Comment: The reason that `switch` statement is invented is because it can (sometimes) be compiled to a jump table, which is more efficient than repeated `if` statement. And that is only possible when the case expression is an integer constant.

Comment: You can switch on expressions though, such as  `switch (score/10)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch case in C is really just a **computed goto**, not a comparison and jump to the next case if condition isn't match so it can't support case comparisons like that.

Besides your example is incorrect. If C < 60 the score will match all 4 cases, so where will it jump? Same to C < 70 when it matches 3 cases and so on.

GCC supports [case ranges](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Case-Ranges.html) extension but not like you expected. Anyway you may still use that if needed

```
switch (score)
{

case 0 ... 59:
    cout << "F";
    break;

case 60 ... 69:
    cout << "D";
    break;

case 70 ... 79:
    cout << "C";
    break;

case 80 ... 89:
    cout << "B";
    break;

case 90 ... 100:
    cout << "A";
    break;

default:
    cout << "Out of range\n";
}
```

Of all the languages I know, only Visual Basic supports comparisons in cases like

```vb
Select Case score
    Case Is >= 0 And Is < 60

    Case Is >= 60 And Is < 70

    Case Is >= 70 And Is < 80

    Case Is >= 80 And Is < 90

    Case Is >= 90 And Is <= 100

    Case Else
End Select
```

However the better way to get the range is to divide the score by 10

```
const char* SCORE[] = "FDCBA";
if (score < 60)
    cout << SCORE[0];
else if (score < 100);
    cout << SCORE[score/10 - 5];
else if (score == 100)
    cout << SCORE[4];
```

Of course you still need to make sure that scores aren't less than 0 or higher than 100

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that.

The expression following `case` must be a constant expression. It cannot depend on the value of a variable at run time.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch for a quick reference.